# Movie Player shows Default.png image in background while loading (OS 3.1.2)

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer, iphone-sdk-3.1.2, default.png

I'm using `MPMoviePlayerController` to stream audio/video files from a servrer. It works great on all other OS versions. However, on 3.1.2, it shows the `Default.png` image (used to display at app splash screen) in the background while the movie loads. It only happens for the first time and the player works fine (no image in background) on all subsequent plays.

I have used the following properties:

```
player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone; 
player.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

I have gone through apple documentation and web in general but seems like no one has this problem. Is there any way I can get rid of this image (Default.png) shown as the player's background?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an uninitialized GL texture is briefly being used by the movie player.

Not sure what you can do about that.

Maybe you can hide the player while it loads.

Comment: in that case, i might think of moving this file to somewhere else and then placing it back before the app quits!

Comment: Which file? You can't move Default.png

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to move Default.png somewhere else (may be in the documents directory). Why would you say that it's not movable? Any other idea to overcome this problem?